# Passar JSON.stringify para Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou tentando passar uma table via JSON.stringify, no ajax, está recebendo os dados perfeitamente, porém não consigo passar para o controller.
Estou passando dessa forma:

```
function enviarDados(produtos) {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Novo1","produtos")',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(produtos)

    });
}
```

Porem no controller, eu sempre recebo a list null, já tentei de várias formas, e nenhuma recebe os valores, sempre vem em null.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Novo1(List<PedidosProdutosF> produtos, NovoViewModel model)
{
}
```

Eu não consigo passar JSON.stringify para controller no .NET CORE ?

**EDIT**

Classe `PedidosProdutosF`:

```
[Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public Produto Produto { get; set; }
    public string CodigoProduto { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Quantidade")]
    public int Qtd { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Preço Unitário")]
    public float PrecoUnitario { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Desconto em %")]
    public float DescontoP { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Desconto em R$")]
    public float DescontoV { get; set; }
    public int ICMS { get; set; }
    public float IPI { get; set; }
    public float ISS { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Data da Entrega")]
    public DateTime DataEntrega { get; set; }
    public int QtdFalta { get; set; }
    public float Total { get; set; }
    public float Aliquota { get; set; }
    public float VICMS { get; set; }
    public float VIPI { get; set; }
    public float VISS { get; set; }
    public int ? PedidoFornecedorId { get; set; }
    public PedidoFornecedor PedidoFornecedor { get; set; }
```

Fiz um `console.log(JSON.stringify(produtos));`

Ele me retorna os dados, da seguinte forma:

```
[
  {
      "CodigoProduto":"P00062",
      "DescricaoProduto":"Descrição 62",
      "Qtd":"1",
      "PrecoCusto":"29,00",
      "DescontoP":"0,00",
      "DescontoV":"0,00",
      "Total":"29,00",
      "ICMS":"1",
      "AliquotaICMS":"0,00",
      "vICMS":"0,00",
      "ISS":"0,00",
      "vISS":"0,00",
      "IPI":"0,00",
      "vIPI":"0,00",
      "Qtdfalta":"",
      "ProdutoID":""
  }
]
```

Aqui é como eu passo os dados da table para o ajax, para ser recebido no controller:

```
 $("#btn-enviar").click(function () {
    var produtos = [];

    $('.item').each(function () {
        var entidade = {
            CodigoProduto: $(this).children()[0].innerText,
            DescricaoProduto: $(this).children()[1].innerText,
            Qtd: $(this).children()[2].innerText,
            PrecoCusto: $(this).children()[3].innerText,
            DescontoP: $(this).children()[4].innerText,
            DescontoV: $(this).children()[5].innerText,
            Total: $(this).children()[6].innerText,
            ICMS: $(this).children()[7].innerText,
            AliquotaICMS: $(this).children()[8].innerText,
            vICMS: $(this).children()[9].innerText,
            ISS: $(this).children()[10].innerText,
            vISS: $(this).children()[11].innerText,
            IPI: $(this).children()[12].innerText,
            vIPI: $(this).children()[13].innerText,
            Qtdfalta: $(this).children()[15].innerText,
            ProdutoID: $(this).children()[16].innerText,
        };
           produtos.push(entidade);
    });
    enviarDados(produtos);
});
```

Comment: Você tentou enviar apenas o  `data: produtos`? tem como adicionar um exemplo do Json gerado e da sua classe PedidosProdutosF?

Comment: Tentei data:produtos, porém ele retorna erro, atualizei a pergunta com a classe, e o exemplo do Json.

Comment: Não consigo fazer uns testes agra, mas achei isso aqui no SO, talvez te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779043/post-json-array-to-mvc-controller

Comment: Estou fazendo testes com estes exemplos, mas até agora, sem sucesso.

Comment: Editei com a parte que envio os dados da table para o ajax.

Comment: @marianac_costa, você postou um print do console.log(produtos),  posta o TXT puro para que eu possa simular aqui dentro do meu Javascript?

Comment: [{"CodigoProduto":"P00062","DescricaoProduto":"Descrição 62","Qtd":"1","PrecoCusto":"29,00","DescontoP":"0,00","DescontoV":"0,00","Total":"29,00","ICMS":"1","AliquotaICMS":"0,00","vICMS":"0,00","ISS":"0,00","vISS":"0,00","IPI":"0,00","vIPI":"0,00","Qtdfalta":"","ProdutoID":""}]

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti está ai.

Comment: @marianac_costa fiz testes no ASP.NET MVC 4 e 5 e funcionou perfeitamente, mas eu fiz o teste passando a string direto, faz assim para efeito de teste, quando você cria a variavel `produtos` atribui a ele esse valor  `var produtos = [{ "CodigoProduto": "P00062", "DescricaoProduto": "Descrição 62", "Qtd": "1", "PrecoCusto": "29,00", "DescontoP": "0,00", "DescontoV": "0,00", "Total": "29,00", "ICMS": "1", "AliquotaICMS": "0,00", "vICMS": "0,00", "ISS": "0,00", "vISS": "0,00", "IPI": "0,00", "vIPI": "0,00", "Qtdfalta": "", "ProdutoID": "" }];` e testa enviando o AJAX

Comment: Fiz o teste e não deu certo, será que o problema está no CORE ?

Comment: Acho que sim  marciana , vou verificar se existe algo relacionado

Comment: @marianac_costa atlera `List<PedidosProdutosF> produtos` para `[FromBody]List<PedidosProdutosF> produtos`

Comment: Ele retorna erro, Esta página não está funcionando
Se o problema continuar, entre em contato com o proprietário do site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confira os dados da sua model com os dados que estão sendo passados no seu JSON. Você deve passar valores para todos os campos que não aceitam `null` na sua model. Outro ponto é que no seu JSON possui campos que estão com os nomes diferentes da model, como por exemplo, o campo `AliquotaICMS` que está no JSON possui o nome `Aliquota` na model.

Os tipos de dados também devem ser respeitados ao se passar o objeto Json na requisição Ajax, para isso utilize o `parseInt`, `parseFloat` quando estiver montando seu objeto.

```
$("#btn-enviar").click(function () {
    var produtos = [];

    $('.item').each(function () {
        var entidade = {
            CodigoProduto: $(this).children()[0].innerText,
            //Não existe o campo DescricaoProduto na model, então retirei do Json
            //DescricaoProduto: $(this).children()[1].innerText,
            Qtd: parseInt($(this).children()[2].innerText),
            PrecoUnitario: parseFloat($(this).children()[3].innerText),
            DescontoP: parseFloat($(this).children()[4].innerText),
            DescontoV: parseFloat($(this).children()[5].innerText),
            Total: parseFloat($(this).children()[6].innerText),
            ICMS: parseInt($(this).children()[7].innerText),
            Aliquota: parseFloat($(this).children()[8].innerText),
            vICMS: parseFloat($(this).children()[9].innerText),
            ISS: parseFloat($(this).children()[10].innerText),
            vISS: parseFloat($(this).children()[11].innerText),
            IPI: parseFloat($(this).children()[12].innerText),
            vIPI: parseFloat($(this).children()[13].innerText),
            Qtdfalta: parseInt($(this).children()[15].innerText),
            ProdutoID: parseInt($(this).children()[16].innerText),
            DataEntrega: '2018-08-25',
            Id: 1
        };

           produtos.push(entidade);
    });

    enviarDados(produtos);
});
```

No seu `Controller` adicione `[FromBody]` antes da sua lista de produtos, para informar que esses valores estão vindo do corpo da requisição `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Novo1([FromBody]List<PedidosProdutosF> produtos)
```

Comment: Tentei fazer desta forma, e ele me retorna o seguinte erro: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Continua passando em branco. Editei a pergunta com a forma que pego os dados da table.

Comment: Deu erro, retorna o seguinte erro: Se o problema continuar, entre em contato com o proprietário do site.
HTTP ERROR 415

Comment: Mas agora chega o parâmetro `produtos`?

Comment: Tente alterar na sua chamada ajax seu `dataType: 'json',` para `dataType: 'text'` e `contentType: 'application/json'` para `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`,

Comment: Ele não chega a entrar, eu coloquei o breakpoint, e ele nem entra, já retorna o erro. Alterei para text e mesmo assim acontece o mesmo problema.

Comment: Mariana, não sei da onde você pega o objeto NovoViewModel, mas tire ele dos parâmetros, não tem como o controller receber dois tipos complexos do body da requisição, a menos que os dois estejam dentro de uma viewmodel

Comment: Mesmo assim ele não vai, acontece o mesmo erro. Tem alguma outra forma que eu posso passar esta tabela para a ação ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos eu testei com o model e funcionou aqui

Comment: Mariana, tente alterar sua model para ficar com as propriedades que existem no seu Json. Pelo que vi aqui, sua model não tem todos os campos que existem no seu Json, por exemplo: DescricaoProduto e PrecoCusto (entre outros) não existem na model.

Comment: Passando os parâmetros direto @PedroPaulo ?

Comment: Coloque na sua model **PedidosProdutosF** os parâmetros que estão faltando no Json, mas a controller você deixa assim: `[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Novo1([FromBody]List<PedidosProdutosF> produtos, NovoViewModel model)`

Comment: Quando eu coloco `[FromBody]` ele me retorna erro, a página não carrega.

Comment: Qual erro que ocorre?

Comment: Se o problema continuar, entre em contato com o proprietário do site.
HTTP ERROR 415. Produtos vem em branco mesmo.

Comment: Volta seu ajax para `dataType: 'json'` e `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: @PedroPaulo eu voltei, fiz o teste com o sem, e mesmo assim n deu.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82156/discussion-between-pedro-paulo-and-marianac-costa).

Answer (score 0):

Você está errando em dois pontos, no nome de alguns atributos e no tipo deles, por exemplo você está enviando no seu JSON o vICMS, mas no seu model esta ICMS, e no caso de todos os atributos `float` e `int` você deve usar o `parseFloat` e `parseInt` respectivamente antes de enviar o JSON, dai não terá problemas, e o parâmetro `NovoViewModel` do seu método não esta sendo utilizado e você deve remove-lo.